# How to use Atmega328p-PU from an Uno, on a breadboard without a crystal

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

How do you use Atmega328p-PU from an Uno, on a breadboard without a crystal?

Comment: By changing the fuses to use the internal oscillator.

Comment: You could have the 328P's "fuses" set so it uses it's internal 8Mhz oscillator. In the Arduino IDE you can then select, for example, the Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V (which also runs at 8Mhz)

Comment: How do you set the fuses?

Comment: With a programmer or another Arduino acting as a programmer.

Comment: So all I have to do is bootload it as a Pro Mini 3.3v?

Comment: > `bootload it as a Pro Mini 3.3v?` how do you do that ? There's an `Upload Using Programmer`, which requires that you use a Programmer.

Comment: Go online for a tutorial on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you buy your ATmega as supplied by Microchip, through one of the
large electronic parts resellers, it will come with its default fuse
configuration:

- clock source: internal 8 MHz RC oscillator
- clock prescaler enabled at ÷8, yielding a 1 MHz system clock
- bootloader disabled

You could use it in this configuration, but you will probably want to
disable the prescaler. This can be done by changing the right fuse or,
alternatively, by some code running early in `setup()`. Note that, with
no bootloader, you will need an ISP programmer in order to load the
code. If you want the convenience of serial downloading (i.e. you would
use an FTDI cable rather than an ISP programmer), you will have to burn
the bootloader using an ISP programmer, and adjust the fuses to enable
it and set its size.

If you take the ATmega from an existing Uno board, or buy one
preconfigured with the bootloader, the fuses will be set differently:

- clock source: external crystal
- clock prescaler disabled
- bootloader enabled and sized to 0.5 KiB

In this case you will have to change the clock source.

In any case, you would tell the IDE you are using an Arduino Fio, or a
Pro or Pro Mini with a 328P clocked at 8 MHz. And you will need an
ISP programmer to load either your program or the bootloader. You could
use an Arduino running the “Arduino as ISP” firmware for this.

Check the datasheet for the details on configuring the fuses. You can
also use one of the online fuse calculators, like [this one](https://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc) or [this
one](https://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/).

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another IC like the 555 timers as an external oscillator.